# Firefox 2nd column is having a line break

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox, drop-down-menu

I have 2 dropdowns in which one will be displayed on page depending the selection of a dropdown:

In firefox, I am getting the form:select tag in second line for both the dropdowns. In chrome and IE it is working perfectly as expected.

```js
var flag = 1;

function showHide() {

  if (flag == 1) {
    document.getElementById('dbTypeDropdown1').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('dbTypeDropdown2').style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById('dbTypelable1').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('dbTypelable2').style.display = "block";
    flag = 0;
  } else {
    document.getElementById('dbTypeDropdown1').style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById('dbTypeDropdown2').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('dbTypelable1').style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById('dbTypelable2').style.display = "none";
    flag = 1;
  }
}

function loadHide() {
  document.getElementById('dbTypeDropdown1').style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById('dbTypeDropdown2').style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById('dbTypelable1').style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById('dbTypelable2').style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<body onLoad=loadHide()>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label path="osType" style="text-align: left;" id="osTypelable"><b>Product Type</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select path="osType" style="width:205px; height:25px" id="osTypeDropdown" onChange="showHide()">
          <option value="windows">Windows</option>
          <option value="linux">Linux</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>

    <tr>
      <td id="dbTypelable1">
        <label path="dbType1" style="text-align: left;"><b>Database Type</b>
        </label>
      </td>
      <td id="dbTypeDropdown1">
        <select path="dbType1" style="width:205px; height:25px">
          <option value="embedded">Embedded</option>
          <option value="mssql2008">MS SQL 2008</option>
          <option value="mssql2012">MS SQL 2012</option>
          <option value="mssql2014">MS SQL 2014</option>
          <option value="oracle11">Oracle 11g</option>
          <option value="oracle12">Oracle 12c</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td id="dbTypelable2">
        <label path="dbType2" style="text-align: left;"><b>Database Type</b>
        </label>
      </td>
      <td id="dbTypeDropdown2">
        <select path="dbType2" style="width:205px; height:25px;">

          <option value="embedded">Embedded</option>
          <option value="oracle11">Oracle 11g</option>
          <option value="oracle12">Oracle 12c</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</body>
```

Comment: Share a working example. This means the **rendered** html (not your template code) and the CSS attached. You can use stacksnippets or external services like jsfiddle.net . Edit this question with an example that shows the problem or this should be closed as **offtopic**.

Comment: Read this for more information http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: this is not a raw html-javascript-css code

Comment: If you run the code snippet, the dropdown has a line break. But if u run the same in chrome, there is no line break, only problem is with Firefox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome's error correction is fixing the issue for you, but the issue remains. The problem is not only in Firefox.

You have a few problems:

1. You have multiple `<tr>` tags - you said you wanted to have this in a single row?
2. You are not using `colspan` if you need to have multiple `<tr>` tags.
3. You are using `display: block;` - You cannot use `display: block` on table elements for toggling, because it will break how the table cells work. You can use `display: table-cell` and `display: none`, but not `display: block`.

Here is your modified HTML: (JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1ntn0yh5/ )

```
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label path="osType" style="text-align: left;" id="osTypelable"><b>Product Type</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select path="osType" style="width:205px; height:25px" id="osTypeDropdown" onChange="showHide()">
          <option value="windows">Windows</option>
          <option value="linux">Linux</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td id="dbTypelable1">
        <label path="dbType1" style="text-align: left;"><b>Database Type</b>
        </label>
      </td>
      <td id="dbTypeDropdown1">
        <select path="dbType1" style="width:205px; height:25px">
          <option value="embedded">Embedded</option>
          <option value="mssql2008">MS SQL 2008</option>
          <option value="mssql2012">MS SQL 2012</option>
          <option value="mssql2014">MS SQL 2014</option>
          <option value="oracle11">Oracle 11g</option>
          <option value="oracle12">Oracle 12c</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td id="dbTypelable2">
        <label path="dbType2" style="text-align: left;"><b>Database Type</b>
        </label>
      </td>
      <td id="dbTypeDropdown2">
        <select path="dbType2" style="width:205px; height:25px;">
          <option value="embedded">Embedded</option>
          <option value="oracle11">Oracle 11g</option>
          <option value="oracle12">Oracle 12c</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: I'm happy it worked for you. And please make sure to clean up your table html a little as well. I provided a JSFiddle for you in case you want to test your work. Happy programming!